# Missing one solution of a differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(x)$ be a solution to the differential equation $(1+e^x)y'+ye^x=1$. If $y(0)=2$ then which of the following statements is (are) true.

(A) $y(-4)=0$

(B) $y(-2)=0$

(C) $y(x)$ has a critical point in the interval $(-1,0)$

(D) $y(x)$ has no critical points in the interval $(-1,0)$

This is a question from IIT-JEE advanced. I have the general solution $y=\frac{x}{(1+e^x)} +c$
and if $y(0)=2$ then the specific solution is $y=\frac{x}{(1+e^x)} +2$

But the problem is only the D is true,then. But the answer sheet has A&C as correct answers. But I have checked many times and found no error in my approach.

Maybe I am missing something. Need a hint.

Comment: Your equation $y=\frac{x}{e^x+1}+2$ does not satisfy the original differential equation. Sub in your $y$ and $y'$ on the left hand side and you won't get $1$. You have a mistake in your working.

Comment: Yeah! missed the initial constant.

Comment: @Mockingbird out of curiosity, how much time do you have per question ?

Comment: I am not Indian. Don't ask me. @qbert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To rectify your mistake, note that if your equation were homogeneous, it would be exact and we would have
$$
g(x,y)=y+ye^x=c\implies y=\frac{c}{1+e^x}
$$
And for the particular solution, use variation of parameters and assume a solution of the form
$$
y(x)=\frac{c(x)}{1+e^x}
$$
Then the conditions of your ode require that 
$$
(1+e^x)y'+ye^x=1\implies c'(x)=1\implies c(x)=x+d
$$
and your solution is thus
$$
y(x)=\frac{x+d}{1+e^x}
$$
with $y(0)=2$ implying that $d=4$
$$
y(x)=\frac{x+4}{1+e^x}
$$
That $A$ is true is clear enough. That $C$ is true follows from the IVT applied to 
$$
1-3e^x-xe^x
$$
on the interval in question.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(1+\exp(x))=\exp(x)
\end{equation}
$$

so that

$$
\begin{equation}
(1+\exp(x))\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+\exp(x)y(x)=(1+\exp(x))\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+y(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(1+\exp(x))
\end{equation}
$$

by the product rule your differential equation is then

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[(1+\exp(x))y(x)\right]=1
\end{equation}
$$

which can be integrated

$$
\begin{equation}
(1+\exp(x))y(x)=x+C
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
y(x)=\frac{x+C}{1+\exp(x)}
\end{equation}
$$

Now for the initial condition

$$
\begin{equation}
y(0)=C/2=2
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
C=4
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
y(x)=\frac{x+4}{\exp(x)+1}
\end{equation}
$$

This solution clearly has a single zero at $x=-4$.

Solving for $y'$ in the differential equation

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1-y\exp{x}}{1+\exp{x}}
\end{equation}
$$

Substituting the IVP solution for $y(x)$.

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1-(\frac{x+4}{\exp(x)+1})\exp(x)}{1+\exp{x}}
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=1-(x+3)\exp(x)
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=0,\;\;\; for\;\;\; x=-0.79206
\end{equation}
$$

or rather

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}|_{x=-1}=1-2\exp(-1)=1-\frac{2}{e}>0
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}|_{x=0}=1-3=-2<0
\end{equation}
$$

Since we see that $y'(x)$ is a continuous function of $x$, there exists a $c\in(-1,0)$ for which $y'(c) = 0$.

Comment: are you assuming OP has access to a calculator?

Comment: @qbert and even Wolfram!

Comment: Good point, I edited the post so that I have simply evaluated the derivative at x = -1 and x =0. Since the derivative changes sign somewhere in (-1,0) we know there is a critical point in this region.

Comment: @Mockingbird wolfram can also evaluate odes. What's the point of using it for these problems?